# Original page redirects while new window is blank when using Window.Open

Tags: javascript

I've created a function and am calling it but it doesn't seem to work. A new window opens, but it ends up blank and the original page is the one that is redirected to where the new window is supposed to.

Here is my script:

```
 var bikeWindow;
         function showBike(linkTarget) {
             bikeWindow = window.open(linkTarget, "bikeInfo", "toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=620,height=575");
             bikeWindow.focus();
         }
```

Here is my function call:

```
a href="cannondale.html"  onclick="return showBike();"
```

Any tips?
Thank you.

Comment: You have "return" in your onclick event but no return in your function.

Comment: Also, your function showBike accepts a variable "linkTarget" but you're not throwing that variable to your function. That's why it's opening a blank window. Your code opens a window but has no URL to go to, so the newly opened page is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your function expects a `targetLink` variable as parameter to be used as redirection url, you need to pass the link href to your function, using `this.href`.

This is how should be your code:

**JavaScript:**

```
var bikeWindow;

function showBike(event, linkTarget) {
  event.preventDefault();
  bikeWindow = window.open(linkTarget, "bikeInfo", "toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=620,height=575");
  bikeWindow.focus();
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="cannondale.html" onclick="showBike(event, this.href);">Link</a>
```

**Note:**

The `return` keyword before your function call is useless in the link click event.

**Edit:**

By using `this.href` on the link we are passing the `href` attribute value to our function: where `this` refers to the `<a>` link itself.

Comment: Will default navigation be prevented?

Comment: This has gotten me closer. Thank you. The only problem now is the original webpage and the pop up go to the new webpage

Comment: @guest271314 well pointed out. Thank you, I am editing my code.

Comment: @Yaludje, I edited the code, we need to prevent the link default action.

Comment: Where is `e` defined?

Comment: I just missed that.

Comment: @chsdk i just added "return false" to the <a> html line. it now reads onclick="showBike(this.href); return false;"> and it seems to work

Comment: @Yaludje yes if you use `return false` you are also preventing the default behaviour of the onclick event.

Comment: @chsdk it all works now, thank you. I'm very very new to javascript, i was wondering if you could explain what the adding "this" did, exactly

Comment: @Yaludje You are welcome, I added explanation to the edit in my answer.

Comment: @chsdk done deal. one last question as i'm fiddling with it. you used the 'this.href' to pass to the function. i'm trying to pass "cannondale.html" inside showBike isn't of this.href, but it isn't working. Why? Again, sorry if it's a dumb question. I am new

Comment: If you pass it like this `onclick="showBike(cannondale.html)"`, `cannondale.html` will be interpreted as a JS variable name you need to warp it between quotes so it can be taken as a `string`, so use `onclick="showBike('cannondale.html')"`.